# Create a new postgres user programmatically, without interactive intervention

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to do this in a script:

```
» sudo -u postgres createuser -PE -s user1
Enter password for new role:
```

I do not want `postgres` to ask for the password interactively, so I want to do:

```
» sudo -u postgres createuser -PE -s user1 < /tmp/xxx
```

Where `/tmp/xxx` contains the password for the new user. But it does not work. How to get this working?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do that using plain SQL after connecting as a superuser (e.g. `postgres`) to the database in question:

```
create user user1 password 'foobar'
```

If you need to do this from within a script you can put that into a sql file and then pass this to psql:

```
» sudo -u postgres psql --file=create_user.sql
```

Answer (score 5):

From the shell, you could use an here-document, like:

```
#!/bin/sh

psql -U postgres postgres <<OMG
 CREATE USER lutser password '`cat /tmp/xxx`' ;
OMG
```

BTW: I'don't think it is a good idea to store the password in `/tmp/`, not even temporally.

Comment: I understand but ... how do you enter a password programatically without having that *somewhere*? The way I do it: I have them in a local file (plain text) indexed by password id (that is, the passwords file is password_id:password. This file is protected, and I access it with sudo. This way I can centralize my password management, by having a simple service providing access to this file.

Comment: @blueFast these days in the cloud the best way to do it is to pass the password in via a secure mechanism like a secure key manager like AWS vault. You can do that via environment parameters on startup. That way they can be encrypted.